# How to force a recalculation of non-changing parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### Context of my question

I receive once a day (say, at 01:15), via MQTT, two timestamps for that day: the beginning and the end of an event (this is a home dashboard, the unexciting reality is that these are the times my children are at school that given day).

[image]

What I display today on the dashboard is `9:00 → 17:10`. This information gets updated when a new MQTT message is received and `start` and `end` change.

This works great.

I now would like to add an extra information, to have a display such as

`9:00 → 17:10 (in 27 minutes)`

The `in 27 minutes` part is the time between now and the end of the school day (`17:10` above). I know how to compute and display it (including the fact that it is visible only when "now" is between the start and the end).

This is achieved by a construction such as

```
{{ extractTime(enfant.start) }} → {{ extractTime(enfant.end) }} <span v-if="dansCreneau(enfant.start, enfant.end)">({{dansTime(enfant.end)}})</span>
```

- `extractTime` takes an ISO date and outputs a 24h time
- `dansCreneau` returns a `true` if "now" is between the dates, otherwise `false`
- `dansTime` returns in a humanized way the time between now and the end of the school day

#### My problem

I know how to display it **once** - there is a single calculation of what is between the parenthesis but after that, from Vue perspective, nothing compelling to recalculate - as nothing changes.

I could run a continuous update of (something) via `setInterval( XXX, 55000);` and I wonder what `XXX` should do. I initially thought of forcing `enfant = enfant` there, but that will not change the value of `enfant` so a trigger to recalculate will not happen.

**What is the correct way to force the recalculation, and therefore the update of my remaining time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store `now` in component data and create computed property which will calculate time difference from stored `now` and `enfant.end`

Update `now` in `setInterval`...

See this simple clock example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    now: new Date(),
    timer: null
  },
  computed: {
    time: function() {
      return this.now.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    let self = this;
    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
      self.now = new Date()
    }, 1000)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ time }}</div>
</div>
```